# SQL Server : Select multiple table and show relation even NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

i Have 3 tables.

Issue Table

```
___________________
id_issue | issue   |
1        | issue A |
2        | issue B |
3        | issue C |
___________________
```

Problem Table

```
_______________________
id_problem | problem   |
1          | problem A | 
2          | problem B |
3          | problem C |
_______________________
```

Visi Table. Have fk on 2 tables before

```
__________________________________________
id_visi | visi   | id_problem | id_issue  |
1       | visi A |      1     |     1     |
2       | visi B |      1     |     2     |
3       | visi C |      1     |     3     |
4       | visi D |      2     |     1     |
5       | visi E |      2     |     2     |
___________________________________________
```

i want to combine 3 tables like this. : 
[EDIT]

```
_____________________________________
| visi   | problem       | issue    |
| visi A | problem A     | issue A  |
| visi B | problem A     | issue B  |
| visi C | problem A     | issue C  |
| visi D | problem B     | issue A  |
| visi E | problem B     | issue B  |
| NULL   | problem B     | issue C  |
| NULL   | problem C     | issue A  |
| NULL   | problem C     | issue B  |
| NULL   | problem C     | issue C  |
_____________________________________
```

I had tried JOIN table but it didnt work. The result didn't show NULL's row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need combination of `CROSS JOIN` & `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT visi, 
       ip.id_problem, 
       ip.id_issue 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   issue I 
               CROSS JOIN problem P) ip 
       LEFT JOIN visi v 
              ON ip.id_problem = v.id_problem 
                 AND ip.id_issue = v.id_issue
```

`CROSS JOIN` : To populate all possible combination between two tables (`Issue` & `Problem`).

`LEFT JOIN` : To pull data for matched records from `Visi` and `NULL` for not matched records